# Removing cycles from a linked list consisting of a graph structure is not working (C language)

Tags: c, list, graph-theory

I have a **graph** structure where each **graph** refers to a vertex on the linked list, and each vertex has one or more **edges**. So I try to remove cycles from the graph. Each **edge** structure has a path that I set as **True** if I alerady used that **edge** as a path. Each **edge** is a linked list inside each **vertex** in the **graph**

So this is what is happening... let's suppose I have a node with the following edges:

```
node ID: 8 edge src: 8 edge dst: 33
node ID: 8 edge src: 8 edge dst: 40
```

These are directed edges and this means that they start on a **source id** and they end on a **destination id**

If I delete the first edge "**node ID: 3 edge src: 8 edge dst: 33**" and inside the function "**remove_graph_cycles**" I print all edges... so all works fine...
the node only prints one edge like this:

```
node ID: 8 edge src: 8 edge dst: 40
```

The problem is when I print all the graph outside this function. Outside the function it prints like this:

```
node ID: 8 edge src: 8 edge dst: 33
node ID: 8 edge src: 8 edge dst: 40
```

I do not understand why... because I just deleted the first edge... and then I get the error: **INVALID READ** or **INVALID WRITE** and the program crashes.

I have the following removing function:

```
void remove_graph_cycles(graph_node** graph)
{
    if((*graph) == NULL){
        return;
    }
    else{
        if((*graph)->edge != NULL){
            if((*graph)->edge->path == true && (*graph)->edge_count > 1){
                delete_edge((*graph)->edge, &(*graph)->edge);
                (*graph)->edge_count--;
            }
         }
        graph_edge* temp = (*graph)->edge;
        while((*graph)->edge != NULL){
            if((*graph)->edge->path == false){
                (*graph)->edge->path = true;
                remove_graph_cycles(&((*graph)->edge->node));
            }
            if((*graph)->edge != NULL){
                (*graph)->edge = (*graph)->edge->next;
            }
            else break; 
        }
        (*graph)->edge = temp;
    }
}
```

This is the delete edge function:

```
void delete_edge(graph_edge* edge, graph_edge** head)
{
    if (edge->src_id == (*head)->src_id && edge->dst_id == (*head)->dst_id) {
        graph_edge* temp = *head;
        *head = (*head)->next;
        free(temp);
        return;
    }
    graph_edge* current = (*head)->next;
    graph_edge* previous = *head;
    while (current != NULL && previous != NULL) {
        if (edge->src_id == current->src_id && edge->dst_id == current->dst_id) {
            graph_edge* temp = current;
            previous->next = current->next;
            free(temp);
            return;
        }
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    return;
}
```

that is how I print the graph:

```
while(*graph != NULL){

graph_edge* edge_list = (*graph)->edge;

printf("---------------------node id:%d ", (*graph)->id); printf("edge count: %d\n\n", (*graph)->edge_count);

    while(edge_list != NULL){

         printf("%d ", edge_list->node->id);
         printf("%s \n\n",edge_list->node->node_name); 

         edge_list = edge_list->next;

    }

    printf("\n\n----------------------------------------------------\n\n");

*graph = (*graph)->next;}
```

I print each node of the graph side by side with the pointer **next**. Each **edge** is an structure with **source** and **destination** **id** and a **node** in the graph which it points to.

Below is the link for the data structure:

[Data structure](https://github.com/rvmelo/mais-ids-acg-sdn/blob/master/graph.h)

Comment: Please clean up the indentation in your code so that it's consistent. It's very hard to read otherwise.

Comment: I think understanding your problem requires more context too, such as a main function demonstrating exactly what you did, and possibly also the type definitions of your data structures. As it is it's not clear to me what you're doing.

Comment: Why does an edge that goes from node 8 to node 40 have anything to do with node 3? Please show your data type definitions.

Comment: the main function is in the file **sdn-selection.c**  in this link: [link] https://github.com/rvmelo/mais-ids-acg-sdn

Comment: I edited the code with a printing example and the link for the data structures

Comment: Again, why does an edge that goes from node 8 to node 40 is referenced by node 3? Normally an edge should be referenced by its source node, and possibly destination node.

Comment: You also should not link to an external (large) code base, but post a [mcve].

Comment: As for your data structure: you should separate the graph data structure from the payload data structure. You graph stuff will then be generic.

Comment: sorry... about the edge it was a mystake.. the node id is 8 and it goes from 8 to 40

Comment: it is already edited with the example fixed